# Can we develop .net framework 4.6.1 supporting office applications using Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, .net-3.5, .net-4.6.1

I have developed an outlook VSTO addin using VS 2008, supporting .net 3.5 . Now, I want to upgrade the .net framework version supported by my application to the latest .net 4.6.1 version. So, will I have to get Visual Studio 2015 for that, or any prior version will suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can target 4.6.1 .net framework with visual studio 2012 or later. You must install.NET Framework 4.6.1 Dev Pack.
https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=49978

Source :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx